# Image in google drive can't get displayed on Mobile Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, google-drive-api

I am trying to display an image stored in google drive on my website. I am using the following format:

```
<img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=XXXX" />
```

I am using the file id referred from the file's sharable link and I made sure the file is publicly shared.

I believe the above link in the src attribute does `307 Internal Redirect`, which opens another url and requests the actual image.  This mechanism seems to work on all browsers but somehow it doesn't work on mobile chrome.
I tried the following format but still no luck.

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=open&id=XXXX
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXX
```

Does anyone know how to use an image in google drive and show it on a website on `Mobile Chrome`?

Comment: Can you post the actual link? Because my guess is you can only see it as long as you're logged in.

Comment: Here is the actual link: https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1FegmaKemElRGWduvjaJzTfl16vxToDNs

The img tag seems to work on Mobile Chrome after I directly open the link, which caches authorization token or sth.  I am looking for a way to show the img tag on mobile chrome without opening the link directly so that users don't need to do anything to see the img on the website.

Comment: For some reason, it works with mobile chrome incognito mode but not with normal mode

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, for example, instead of use of the direct link, how about displaying the image file downloaded from Google Drive by Javascript?

Comment: How are you testing it? Do you encounter this issue with other devices?

Comment: @Mr.Rebot I tried with mobile chrome on different devices and encountered the same issue.

Comment: @masanorinyo Thank you for replying. If you tried that, can you provide the result? Such information will be also useful for users including me.